# Getting tcsh dextract-like pushd functionality in bash

Tags: bash, tcsh, pushd

I love `bash` (4.1.2(1)-release) but I strongly prefer the way `tcsh` implements `pushd +N` with the `dextract` option enabled, so much so that I refuse to use `bash` as my default shell because of it. Has anyone implemented a `dextract`-like directory stack set of commands in `bash` or maybe I haven't figured out how to coax `bash` to behave like `tcsh` with `dextract` enabled?

The sticking point: The order that `bash` leaves the directory stack in after a `pushd +N`. For example:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ pushd a
/tmp/a /tmp
$ pushd ../b
/tmp/b /tmp/a /tmp
$ pushd ../c
/tmp/c /tmp/b /tmp/a /tmp
$ pushd +1
/tmp/b /tmp/a /tmp /tmp/c
```

Why does `bash` (and default `tcsh`) rotate the positions of all the other directories when I do a `pushd +1`? Why is this useful? (Perhaps if someone explained, I might appreciate the behavior and get used to it.) Compare to `tcsh` with `dextract`, which just extracts it and puts it on top:

```
% set dextract
% cd /tmp
% pushd a
/tmp/a /tmp 
% pushd ../b
/tmp/b /tmp/a /tmp 
% pushd ../c
/tmp/c /tmp/b /tmp/a /tmp 
% pushd +1
/tmp/b /tmp/c /tmp/a /tmp
```

Note that the remaining order of the directories is untouched. I consider this important because  it's easier to keep track in my mind when the order doesn't get rotated, and so I don't have to be always doing a `dirs` and searching for the directory I want.

If I were to take a crack at it, where would I start? I see there is a variable `DIRSTACK`, but it is not correct (it's empty when the stack has four entries), although changing it does alter the stack (not correctly though).

Answer (score 0):

After some work and inspiration, I solved my problem:

```
# dextract-like pushd -- push $1'st directory to top of stack and shift rest down
function pushd {
    local t
    if [[ $1 =~ ^[-+]?[0-9]+$ ]]; then
        pos=$1
        [[ ${pos} -lt 0 ]] && ((pos=${#DIRSTACK[@]}+${pos}))
        if [[ ${pos} -gt 0 && ${pos} -lt ${#DIRSTACK[@]} ]]; then
            t="${DIRSTACK[$pos]}"
            # This is crufty. You can't put ~ in DIRSTACK, except the
            # shell will put it into position zero when it refers to your
            # own directory (not anyone else's!). So replace any occurrences.
            DIRSTACK=("" "${DIRSTACK[0]/#~/${HOME}}" "${DIRSTACK[@]:1:${pos}-1}" "${DIRSTACK[@]:${pos}+1}")
            cd "$t"
            builtin dirs -v
        else
            echo "$0: pushd: $1: directory stack index out of range" 1>&2
        fi
    else
        builtin pushd "$@" >/dev/null || return
        cd .
        builtin dirs -v
    fi
}
```

Comment: You are right about quoting, thank you. I don't want to swap the given directory with the top directory, I want to push the given directory on the top so that the current directory is now second, and the second directory is now third, and so forth. DIRSTACK is rather finicky about being set, which is why I used a separate array to do the manipulation.

Comment: Yes, I was only thinking about `pd +1`, sorry. In DIRSTACK you cannot splice entries in or out, or set `DIRSTACK[0]` (it will silently fail)

Comment: Still, you can get rid of the `tempstack` array: `pd(){ local t=${DIRSTACK[$1]}; DIRSTACK=("" "${DIRSTACK[@]:0:$1}" "${DIRSTACK[@]:$1+1}"); cd "$t"; dirs; }`